# undefined reference in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

The following compiles under `cleveref` `v0.19` and `tcolorbox` `v3.80` with TeXLive 2013 under osx 10.6.8 but the reference does not work. I have added an example (commented out) from the doc where the reference does work.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk  
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  

%\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within= chapter, crefname={bluebox}{blueboxes}] {mybluebox}[2][]{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=Bluebox \thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={example}{examples},Crefname={EXAM}{EXAMS}]{EXAM}[2][]{fonttitle=\small\sffamily,detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},fontupper=\small\sffamily,coltitle=black,colback=white, colframe=white,title={\textbf{E\footnotesize{XAM} \small{\thetcbcounter}: #2,#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

%\begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title} 
%This is an example
%\end{mybluebox}
%\Cref{myreference} on \cpageref{myreference}

\begin{EXAM}[label={zap}]{Some Title}
This is my own box.
\end{EXAM}
\Cref{zap} on \cpageref{zap}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reference in the documentation example works because of the limiting of `,` for the title argument. The title ends at `#2`, after that the optional argument `#1` comes into action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo or wrongly set `}` in the definition of `EXAMS` box:

Original version:

```
title={\textbf{E\footnotesize{XAM} \small{\thetcbcounter}: #2,#1}
```

This means that the `label={zap}` is appended to the title, which is pretty useless.

The correct form is of course

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={example}{examples},Crefname={EXAM}{EXAMS}]{EXAM}[2][]{%
  fonttitle=\small\sffamily,detach title,
  before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
  fontupper=\small\sffamily,
  coltitle=black,colback=white, 
  colframe=white,
  title={\textbf{E\footnotesize{XAM} \small{\thetcbcounter}: #2}},
  #1
}
```

i.e. closing `title={...}`, then applying the optional argument `#1`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  

%\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within= chapter, crefname={bluebox}{blueboxes}] {mybluebox}[2][]{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=Bluebox \thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={example}{examples},Crefname={EXAM}{EXAMS}]{EXAM}[2][]{%
  fonttitle=\small\sffamily,detach title,
  before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
  fontupper=\small\sffamily,
  coltitle=black,colback=white, 
  colframe=white,
  title={\textbf{E\footnotesize{XAM} \small{\thetcbcounter}: #2}},
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

%\begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title} 
%This is an example
%\end{mybluebox}
%\Cref{myreference} on \cpageref{myreference}

\begin{EXAM}[label={zap}]{Some Title}
This is my own box.
\end{EXAM}
\Cref{zap} on \cpageref{zap}

\end{document}
```

In conjunction with such settings with `tcolorbox` it's a good idea to provide the options on a separate line for each option.

[image]

Comment: Would you believe I spent several hours looking for an error even though it is my standard procedure to "provide the options on a separate line for each option"? (That's because I am only a user with no time left to really learn and understand LaTeX.)

Comment: @schremmer: I actually wanted to say that it's better to use one line per option to make the usage more distinguishable. `LaTeX` actually doesn't care about one line per option or writing them all in one line only ;-)

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer That much I knew. But what I don't really know is the use of % at the end of each line. But that's for another time.